# possible for a modal window to automatically scroll to a designated point?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone tell me...

Would it be possible to open an external webpage in a modal window... and have that new page scroll to a certain point (e.g an anchor)?

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but unless you can inject script into the page and create an anchor to scroll to, then no.

Most developers would by now actively block XSS.

You may have a chance if you grab the generated html and inject into it before displaying but what a pain that would be

Comment: If however it does already have the anchor, simply opening it by `url#anchor` should work.